# Failed to compile ./src/App.js Module not found: Can't resolve

Tags: reactjs, module, compilation, resolve

I got following error when I start to run the local server:

> Failed to compile ./src/App.js Module not found: Can't resolve
>   './Main' in '/home/sol/React/kuehnfotografie/src'

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Main from './Main';
import { Provider, createComponent } from 'react-fela';
import { createRenderer } from 'fela';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="content">
        <Main />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

[Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HaqjO.png)

This is the main.js file:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider, createComponent } from 'react-fela';
import { createRenderer } from 'fela';
import Header from './main/Header';
import Content from  './main/Content';
import Footer from './main/Footer';

class Main extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="main">
        <Header />
        <Content />
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
} 

export default Main;
```

Comment: Main is a folder not file, so either it should be `./main` or Main folder should contain the `index.js` file.

Comment: I've a folder called "Main" and a file calles "main.js"

Comment: you want to render `main.js` file or any file inside Main folder??

Comment: I want to render main.js ... your comment solved the problem. (changed it to ./main) Thanks, but now I got the same issue with main.js and so on. Never ends.

Comment: can you show the code of `main.js` file also?

Comment: Of course, if you can tell me, how to include it in the comments.

Comment: use this: `import Header from './Main/Header'; 
import Content from './Main/Content'; 
import Footer from './Main/Footer'; ` it should be `Main` not `main` :)

Comment: see here you are importing the Header and Content component from Main folder, use the same name that you defined. File name is `main.js` but folder name is `Main`, be careful with the names :)

Comment: I see what you mean, but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: can you paste the error message?

Comment: Failed to compile
./src/main.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './Main/Content' in '/home/sol/React/kuehnfotografie/src'

Comment: that means file Content  doesn't exist, i think you defined that as `content` (small c), check all the names and use the same name when importing the component. it should be `./Main/content` and `./Main/header`.

Comment: I got it. There were so many declarationproblems like it never stops to throw out a failure. Thank you so much for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove

> package-lock.json

, run

> npm install

and then

> npm run

start again.

Comment: This does not help.